# How to find what degree on a circle is tangent to a point outside of that circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

- I know the (x,y) of a point, P, outside of a circle.
- I know the (x,y) for the origin of a circle, O.
- I know the radius, r, of that circle.

How would I find what degree (e.g. 20 degrees, 270 degrees) is tangent to the point outside of the circle?

SOLUTION:

Hello Internet!
So I ended up using the "circle form" formula at this reference http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circles2/CirclePoint/CirclePointDistance.htm to calculate the (x,y) coordinates of the point on the circle (radius not @ 0,0)
Then I used: atan( y-Oy / x-Ox ) * 180/PI to get the 'degree' at that tangent point.

Comment: How can a degree be tangent to a point?

Comment: Also, there can be more than one tangent (usually, there are two possible choices)

Comment: If I’m right, you want to know the **angle between the tangency points** of the tangents through P (centered at O)?

Comment: You’re going through _way_ too much work to compute this angle.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a figure is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Can you draw the second tangent?

Can you calculate $d$?

At what angle does the tangent line strike the radius?

Can you use the Pythagorean Theorem?

Can you calculate $s$?

Comment: Are Pythagoras or s useful when sin(required_angle / 2) = r/d ?